# Flash Game objects won't go away

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash movie with a interactive game in the middle. The game is a simple drag and drop with a target.

Now to my problem:
When the user plays the game the drag and drop symbols stays in the target spot on the next frame to the end of the movie.

I would like them to disappear after the game is over. 
I am a noobie to actionscript 3.0 - is the a code i can implement on the frames after the game to make sure that the objects wont showup.

Thanks..

Comment: Can you please show what code do you currently have?

Answer (score 2):

Frame navigation does not affect objects that were created by code (or even objects that were created by frames but modified by code). So you need to manually remove them via `removeChild()`.